# jQuery to select and update radio button value

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am using the below jQuery to take the data from radio button, every-time it is showing the first checked option, on changing the option it is not updating and keep alerting the same option.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($("input[name=options_1]").is(':checked')) {
       $ans = $("input[name=options_1]:checked").val();
       $(':radio').removeProp('checked');
       $(".submit_ans").click(function () {

          alert($ans);
          $('.viewans').removeClass('disabled');
          $('.next_ques').removeClass('disabled');
       });
       $('.next_ques').click(function () {
          $('.ques_1').hide();
          $('.ques_2').show(); // the html has other questions as well but not shown in the code below. 
          $('.viewans').addClass('disabled');
          $('.next_ques').addClass('disabled');

       });
    }

    $(".viewans").click(function () {
       $(".hide_options").toggle("slow");
    });

 });
```

HTML :

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="radio col-lg-3">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="a" id="optionsRadios1" name="options_1">
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio col-lg-3">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="b" id="optionsRadios2" name="options_1">b
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio col-lg-3">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="c" id="optionsRadios3" name="options_1">c</label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio col-lg-3">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="d" id="optionsRadios4" name="options_1">d
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle.net example with your full post-rendered code including the `".submit_ans"` button.

Comment: where is your full code

Answer (score 1):

enclose the if condition within a change event of `options_1` :

```
$("input[name=options_1]").change(function(){
..
}
```

like:

```
 $("input[name=options_1]").change(function(){
     if($("input[name=options_1]").is(':checked'))
            {
                $ans = $("input[name=options_1]:checked").val();
                $(':radio').removeProp('checked');
                       alert($ans);

            }
  });
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AcaLJ/)

Comment: +1 it worked but here in localhost its not reseting using $(':radio').removeProp('checked');